# regEx parsing string which optionally repeats the same pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a long string that represents an array of person. The string contains either one or many repeating pattern, one per user. It is in the form of:

For a single person:

```
6;#Pierre,#stuff about Pierre
```

For multiple persons, the separator is "`;#`" and the pattern repeats itself:

```
"6;#Pierre,#stuff about Pierre;#8;#Luigi,#more stuff about Luigi"
```

The regEx that I use works for a single user and extracts the name and the `"more stuff"`

```
/(\d+)(?:;#)(.*)(?:,#)(.*)/
```

I have being trying to build a Regex that allow me to figure out if there is another person to process, but I can't find a way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would discourage your usage of `(.*)` because it greedily matches absolutely any character (including, say `;#8`, for instance). More about greediness on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

I would do this:

```
(\d+);#(.*?),#(.*?)(?=;#|$)
```

The `?` makes the `.*` lazy and the `(?=;#|$)` lookahead still enforces that after the last capture-group (with the more info) there is either another person or the end of the string.

You can see it work in this [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM6jH6/2).

Comment: The term "discouraged" would suggest that you shouldn't ever use it ;-)

Comment: @Ja͢ck rephrased it a bit, but my advise is not far from what you say it suggests **:)** if `.*` can be avoided, avoid it. This can usually be done either with a negative class like `[^;#]*` or by making it lazy as I do in my answer.

Comment: This is probably nitpicking, but discouraging or suggesting would imply that something is already working ... except that it's not :) besides that, greediness has its place, though it's probably lost on OP heh

Comment: @Ja͢ck Hah, but I'm not discouraging use of greediness! I'm discouraging greediness in combination with the `.` because it matches any character. But you are right in that I meant that in a general way, not only this case specifically, where "discouraging" implies _"although this works, do it differently"_ when it doesn't work to begin with. Ever considered a career in law? **;)**

Comment: No, but perhaps we should start a firm together :D

Comment: wow, I am impressed, this is exactly what I wanted. And I leaned new stuff with regEx!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of positive lookahead and see if `;#` is followed by a `\d+` and then we will use `Array.map` to split on either `,` or `;#`

```
var arr = str.split(/;#(?=\d+)/).map(function(str){ 
    return str.split(/;#|,/);
});
```